# view pdf file in linux terminal without sudo installing

Tags: terminal, pdf

I want to know how I can view pdf files without using any packages that need `sudo` command to be installed because I don't have `sudo` access.

I tried to use okular but it didn't work for me:

```
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/okular
cd okular
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/your/install/dir ..
make
make install
```

I didn't understand the path to my install (it's a folder that already exists or what).

THank you very much

Comment: Do you really need to view these in a terminal? Or do you mean you want to launch a _graphical_ command to view a PDF from the terminal? Also, what distribution are you using? Do you have a graphical environment? If so, which one? Doesn't it come with a PDF viewer installed? Finally, if your `make` command worked, then you don't need the `make install`, you should be able to run okular from the directory where you just compiled it.

Answer (score 0):

It is where you want it installed to. You can probably skip this. As you can also run it from the build directory. However this is what you need to do:

- Do `mkdir "$HOME/3rd-party-stuff"`
- Then change `/path/to/your/install/dir` to `"$HOME/3rd-party-stuff"`.